# Best Table Relationship Design for Similar Entities

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ms-access

I am trying to figure out the best way to set up my Entity Diagram. I will explain based on the image below.

tblParentCustomer: This table stores information for our Primary Customers, which can either be a Business or Consumer.(They are identified using a lookup table tblCustomerType.)

tblChildCustomer: This table stores customers that are under the Primary Customer. The Primary Business customers can have Authorized Employees and Authorized Reps. The Primary Consumer customers can have Authorized Users. (They are identified using a lookup table tblCustomerType.)

tblChildAccountNumber: This table stores AccountNumbers for tblChildCustomer. These account numbers are mainly for the Child Business Customers. I may be adding Account Numbers for the Child Consumer customers, I am not sure yet, but I believe this design will allow for that if/when necessary.

Going back to tblParentCustomer : If this customer is a Consumer, I will need to add account numbers for them. My question is, do I create a 1 - Many relationship between tblParentCustomer and tblParentAccountNumber? This option would give me 2 different Account Number Tables.

Or would it make sense to create a Junction Account Table that intersects tblParentCustomer and tblChildCustomer?

The first option doesn't really make sense to me because what if there is only 1 Account number for a customer but multiple childCustomers?

Does it make sense to have 2 similar Account Tables that serve a different purpose?

[image]

Comment: Does one Customer have one AccountNumber or can one Customer have multiple AccountNumbers? If one Customer only has one AccountNumber, AccountNumber should be included directly in the Customer table. The AccountNumber can be used as a primary key if the AccountNumber will never change too.

Comment: Can ChildAccountNumber have the same numbers as ParentAccountNumber?  If not, why put them in 2 separate tables?  Just designate between the two with a field named Parent that's set to True or False.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a many-to-many the way you want it to be, you need a link table that will make the whole thing go from 1-* and then *-1
That link table will have two FK, one linking to the parentTable and one linking to the childTable. Combination of those two FK will give you a composite PK (this is important to avoid duplicates). It will allow for any customer to be part of as many accounts as possible (duh.. it'll make the parent/child table a many-to-many relationship).
This approach is extremely common with regards to CRM or any Accounts containing people. Bring it one step further and in that table, you might want to add a "is primary contact" in the AccountMembers table. Drop the childAccountNumber table; you don't need it. [image]

[image]

Comment: Furthermore, if each account _can_ have only one parent account, have a field in the account stating the parent account id. If more than one, create another relational table similar to accountMembers with two fk making a combined PK both pointing to account name it like ParentAccountID and ChildAccountID. That's the way to go.